# How to compare dates with string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction_Date'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')` which seems to work fine. However, I really annoyingly I still seem to have to use month/day/year format when I compare dates. As in

```
df[(df['date'] > "04/10/2018") & (df['date'] < "05/10/2018")]
```

Is there any way to persuade pandas to allow day/month/year format when comparing dates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, not unless you convert to datetime beforehand.

```
from functools import partial

f = partial(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)
df[(df['date'] > f("04/10/2018")) & (df['date'] < f("05/10/2018"))]
```

Alternatively,

```
df['date'].between(f("04/10/2018"), f("05/10/2018"))
```

Otherwise, if you want to compare the strings, the format *must* be YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: That's confusing as `df[(df['date'] > "04/10/2018") & (df['date'] < "05/10/2018")]` does appear to work which is not in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: @Anush it's likely doing either lexicographical or month-first comparisons and failing.

Comment: Can the `dayfirst=True` be set when `f` is defined so I don't have to add it each time?

Comment: @Anush great idea. Yes, you can do that using `functools.partial`. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you want is some "syntax sugar"...

If you have a lambda function such as

```
l = lambda x: datetime(*[int(_) for _ in x.split('/')[::-1]])
```

than you can just wrap your dates using `day/month/year` and the function will convert that for you.

```
df[(df['date'] > l("04/10/2018")) & (df['date'] < l("05/10/2018"))]
```

My function is just an example, you can define whatever function you'd think fits. There are infinite possibilities